# Titanium Random App Crash At Launch

Tags: android, titanium, titanium-mobile

I am using titanium 3.1.0 GA. The app usually runs fine. But sometimes when launched, it crashes at random occasions on actual device. Following is the screenshot of the crash:

[image]

This doesn't seem to be a problem in my application, since most of times and in all possible scenarios, the app launches fine. But sometimes on the same device, the problem occurs. But still I show my code of app.js file, just in case:

```
//bootstrap and check dependencies
if (Ti.version < 1.8)
{
    alert('Sorry - this application template requires Titanium Mobile SDK 1.8 or later');
}

(function()
{
    var Window = require('ui/common/HomeScreenWindow');
    new Window().open();

    var and = Ti.Android;
    if(and)
    {
        var ca=and.currentActivity;
        if(ca)
        {
            var intent=ca.getIntent();
            if(intent.hasExtra("from_my_background_service"))
            {
                var cinemaName=intent.getStringExtra("cinemaName");
                var cityName=intent.getStringExtra("cityName");
                var moviesList=JSON.parse (intent.getStringExtra("moviesList"));
                var MovieTimingWindow = require('ui/common/MoviesInTheatres');
                new MovieTimingWindow(moviesList,cityName,cinemaName).open();
            }
        }
    }
})();
```

I was able to get the following stacktrace:

```
D/dalvikvm(  525): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 1592K, 21% free 28277K/35648K, paused 90ms, total 90ms
W/InputMethodManagerService(  525): Starting input on non-focused client com.android.internal.view.IInputMethodClient$Stub$Proxy@428c4c80 (uid=10076 pid=8393)
I/ActivityManager(  525): START u0 {act=android.intent.action.MAIN cat=[android.intent.category.LAUNCHER] flg=0x10200000 cmp=uk.co.planetbeyond.mobilinkmoviealerts/.Mobilink_chalo_cinemaActivity} from pid 842
D/dalvikvm(  525): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 5603K, 23% free 23830K/30848K, paused 87ms, total 87ms
I/dalvikvm-heap(  525): Grow heap (frag case) to 27.987MB for 4915216-byte allocation
D/dalvikvm(  525): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 1K, 20% free 28629K/35652K, paused 75ms, total 75ms
I/TiRootActivity( 8393): (main) [0,0] checkpoint, on root activity create, savedInstanceState: null
D/dalvikvm(  525): GC_CONCURRENT freed 1125K, 20% free 28626K/35652K, paused 6ms+9ms, total 128ms
E/TiExceptionHandler( 8393): (main) [94,94] ----- Titanium Javascript Runtime Error -----
E/TiExceptionHandler( 8393): (main) [0,94] - In ti:/titanium.js:139,10
E/TiExceptionHandler( 8393): (main) [0,94] - Message: Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function
E/TiExceptionHandler( 8393): (main) [0,94] - Source:        return contextRequire(path, context, sourceUrl);
E/V8Exception( 8393): Exception occurred at ti:/titanium.js:139: Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function
V/PhoneStatusBar(  622): setLightsOn(true)
I/TiRootActivity( 8393): (main) [0,0] checkpoint, on root activity resume. activity = uk.co.planetbeyond.mobilinkmoviealerts.Mobilink_chalo_cinemaActivity@42472168
I/ActivityManager(  525): Displayed uk.co.planetbeyond.mobilinkmoviealerts/.Mobilink_chalo_cinemaActivity: +307ms
I/TiAnalyticsSvc( 8393): (Thread-3092) [29957,29957] Analytics Service Started
I/TiAnalyticsSvc( 8393): (Thread-3092) [2689,32646] Stopping Analytics Service
D/dalvikvm(26566): GC_CONCURRENT freed 545K, 6% free 10636K/11284K, paused 11ms+2ms, total 64ms
```

Comment: its not a random creash probably you are doing trying to access function which is not actual a function

Comment: plz share your code here

Comment: @Wahhab_mirza I have added my code. Please have another look

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing (just a guess) that it has something to do with the intent you are requesting. Try to see if that happens if there's an intent (and if not).

What I would do is write an numbered 'info' to the console after each line to see what the last number before the crash happens. the line after that number is the problematic one.